# ComboBox - Detect if change is by Human or Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

How to detect if the change event `SelectedIndexChanged()` is done by a Human (*Clicks*) or programmatically?

```
private void MyComboBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("MouseDown...");
}
private void MyComboBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("MouseUp...");
}
private void MyComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("SelectionChangeCommitted...");
}
private void MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("SelectedIndexChanged... By Human or Programmatically?");
}
```

**Notes**

- Click event [does not get fired on ComboBox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486927/c-sharp-combobox-how-to-capture-a-mouseclick-on-a-item-in-the-list), but only when you click on the ComboBox itself.
- I have hundreds of function calls that change the ComboBox programmatically, so adding a flag on each one will be very hard to do.

**How to know if the event `SelectedIndexChanged()` is By Human or Programmatically?**

Comment: Exactly why do you need to distinguish how the change was made? What problem are you trying to answer?

Comment: There is a `UpdateServer()` function that gets called when `IndexChanged` event gets fired, the problem is we don't want that function to get called if a Human does the change.

Comment: Do these ComboBoxes change programmatically after the form is on the screen?  If not, then you can just set a flag after the form is loaded.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "programmatically"? the application will run, items will be loaded to the combobox, and the selected index will be changed programmatically without human interaction?

Comment: `SelectionChangeCommitted` is called before `SelectedIndexChanged`. You can set a flag when the former is called, so you know the change is caused by User action. No flag set, done in code

Comment: To avoid XY problem ->"Programmatically" means there is a separate thread that updates the COmboBox continually every couple of seconds. When the change gets fired we need to know if it's by that thread or by a Human click.

Comment: @jimi are you sure? I will give it a try right now.

Comment: @Jimi that's it !!! That is exactly what we should do. a simple one flag in `SelectionChangeCommitted` did the trick. Please create an answer so other guys in the future benefit from it. Thank you.

Comment: Do note this from the documentation for the SelectionChangeCommitted event : "_However, depending on how the ComboBox is configured, and how the user changes the selected item, the SelectionChangeCommitted event may not be raised._" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That's scary, but, in my case, the `SelectionChangeCommitted` get fired only when the user makes changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has worked for me is to set a flag on the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event which is only fired when the change is cause by user input.

[image: differentiate changes]

---

**Example**

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox.Items.AddRange(
        new object[] 
        { 
            Color.Red, 
            Color.Green, 
            Color.Blue, 
        });
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // Programmatically change CB
    numericUpDown.Maximum = 2;
    numericUpDown.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => 
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = (int)numericUpDown.Value;

    comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _isUserChange= true;
    };

    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        string msg = _isUserChange ? "USER CHANGE" : "PGM CHANGE";

        richTextBox.SelectionColor = (Color)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        richTextBox.AppendText($"{msg}{Environment.NewLine}");

        numericUpDown.Value = (int)comboBox.SelectedIndex;
        _isUserChange= false;
    };
}
bool _isUserChange = false;
```

Comment: Yes, `SelectionChangeCommitted` is the way to do that. Thank you for the screenshots and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Catch `Enter` and `Leave` events. Human changes cannot be made without first entering. Set and clear flag like `bool my_cb_focus;`

Comment: The problem with that solution would be if any of the programmatic function calls could happen while the mouse is over the combobox.

Comment: I see, I will give it a try now. I hope the `Leave` event gets fired after the `Changed` event, otherwise won't work. If the user uses a keyboard to navigate, this solution won't work either.

Comment: @AlbertShown I tried Up/Down arrow keys and they fire index change before Leave.

Comment: See also `GetLastInputInfo` Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool value to tell the event to return instantly like this:

```cs
private bool myComboBoxAllowIndexChangeEvent = true;
private void MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!myComboBoxAllowIndexChangeEvent)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("SelectedIndexChanged Programmatically");
      return;
   }

   Console.WriteLine("SelectedIndexChanged By Human");
}

private void SelectSomeComboBox() {
   myComboBoxAllowIndexChangeEvent = false;

   MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = MyComboBox.FindStringExact("test")

   myComboBoxAllowIndexChangeEvent = true;
}
```

Comment: From the question: `I have hundreds of function calls that change the ComboBox programmatically, so adding a flag on each one will be very hard to do.`

Comment: From what I have read on the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), I don't think it's possible to change the index without notifying the object to trigger it's events.
You can remove the event from the object or have a bool or whatever datatype for one or many boxes to figure out how it got triggered

Comment: @WinjasForce, You are right in your comment, it's not possible (implicit) but at least we should have more priorities about that event, something to know if it's by a click or an API call, etc...